# I want to Change the background color of PopupMenu in my android app, I am using "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"

Tags: android, kotlin, popupmenu, overflow-menu

**I want to customize PopupMenu**, background color as Light Black color and text color as white. I am using "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar" as parent. I tried to customize but there is some white space from up and down in popup menu.
[image]
I want to change the entire PopupMenu background. Please Help

I add ->

```
 <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorLightBlack</item>
 <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
```

**This is My Themes.xml file -> **

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.KawawaMusic" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/transparent</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="bottomNavigationStyle">@style/Widget.App.BottomNavigationView</item>

        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorLightBlack</item>
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="bottom_nav_style">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Widget.App.BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.BottomNavigationView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.BottomNavigationView" parent="">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle"
        parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
<!--        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>-->
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line to your **Base application theme**:

```
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
```

Then create a separate style as shown below:

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#202020</item>
</style>
```